# how fix issues with facebook request dialog that not stop loading?

Tags: javascript, facebook

**situation**
i'm trying to open a request dialog box over my page. But when i click the button the box appear but not stop to loading.

the application not show error in javascript console or something like that

thanks

```
inviteFB = ->
  FB.ui
    method: 'apprequests'
    message: fb_request_message_text
    exclude_ids: fb_request_already_invited || []
    (response) ->
```

[image]

Comment: What's your code like? How are you opening the dialog box?

Comment: i added a part of the code which load the dialog box. it worked before but suddenly not work anymore

Comment: Seems quite partial - perhaps you're using some sort of JS library? The code, as you posted here, is not valid javascript code.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with traditional JS code - did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "to" parameter to pass the list of friends. Just don't pass more then 25 friend ids for example.

This happens to me when passing 50 friends to apprequest dialog. When passing 25 it works fine.

Not sure what is the magic number, tried 26 and still works.

I got the idea to try this because of the IE6/IE7 25 friends per request limitation.